# Find all idle screens

Tags: gnu-screen, ps

I have started a few processes in the past initiated via the `screen` command. Most of those scripts have already finished running, but looks like the screens are still sitting there idle. I can see them when I do a `ps aux | less` to see all processes.

How can I see all the `screen`s and whether there is an active script running in them.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see the current list of running screens:

```
screen -list
```

The first part of the screen's name is its PID. To see the tree of currently running processes spawned from that parent process, run:

```
pstree <PID>
```

or, for a more detailed output,

```
pstree -a <PID> | less
```

To reattach to a screen (and detach it if it's already attached elsewhere), run:

```
screen -rd <PID>
```

To kill a screen once you've established you no longer need it, you have a couple options. If you're currently attached to the screen, you can simply use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, which will kill the screen and all its windows.

Alternatively, if you're not attached to the session, you can use:

```
kill <PID>
screen -wipe <PID>
```

to kill it and remove it from the list of screens.

Comment: Thank you. How can I kill the screen when I find out there is no processes running in it?

Comment: @farjam Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent `screen` from sitting idle after a script finishes by terminating the shell when the script completes:

```
script.sh; exit
```

Or, if you want to have a chance to look at error messages, you could run

```
script.sh && exit
```

That way, `screen` will only close if `script.sh` completed successfully.

Comment: And when the OP finds a time machine, this will answer the question asked.

Comment: I appreciate this answer, however; it is not directly addressing the problem on hand, it is more of a solution to prevent having idle screens in future.

Comment: @ParthianShot are you assuming the OP will never use a computer again, not before he finds a time machine?

Comment: He asked for the time, and you told him to buy a watch.

Comment: @ParthianShot Yes, I did exactly that. You seem to imply it was the wrong thing to do, if so, feel free to downvote, flag it as "not an answer", or bring it up on Meta.

Answer (score 0):

Using this pipe I can get a list of PIDs corresponding to inactive screens

```
screen -list | sed '1d;$d' | sed -r 's/^[^[0-9]]*([0-9]*).*$/\1/' | xargs -n1 pstree -p | sed -r 's/.*bash\(([0-9]+)\)$/\1/' | grep "^[0-9]*$"
```

For example:

```
> screen -list

There are screens on:
    8988.pts-0.ubuntu-1gb-sfo1-01   (07/09/2018 09:02:14 PM)    (Detached)
    8960.pts-0.ubuntu-1gb-sfo1-01   (07/09/2018 09:01:40 PM)    (Detached)
    8927.pts-0.ubuntu-1gb-sfo1-01   (07/09/2018 09:01:02 PM)    (Detached)
    8903.pts-0.ubuntu-1gb-sfo1-01   (07/09/2018 09:00:42 PM)    (Detached)
    8857.pts-0.ubuntu-1gb-sfo1-01   (07/09/2018 08:59:30 PM)    (Detached)
    8831.pts-0.ubuntu-1gb-sfo1-01   (07/09/2018 08:59:01 PM)    (Detached)
6 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-user.

> screen -list | sed '1d;$d' | sed -r 's/^[^[0-9]]*([0-9]*).*$/\1/' | xargs -n1 pstree -p

screen(8988)───bash(8989)
screen(8960)───bash(8961)
screen(8927)───bash(8928)
screen(8903)───bash(8904)
screen(8857)───bash(8858)───python(8877)───{python}(8881)
screen(8831)───bash(8832)───python(8851)───{python}(8855)
```

The first 4 are inactive, so then it's a matter of picking out those PIDs, which can be done with `sed -r 's/.*bash\(([0-9]+)\)$/\1/' | grep "^[0-9]*$"`

What's nice about this is I can kill all the inactive screens with one line:

```
screen -list | sed '1d;$d' | sed -r 's/^[^[0-9]]*([0-9]*).*$/\1/' | xargs -n1 pstree -p | sed -r 's/.*bash\(([0-9]+)\)$/\1/' | grep "^[0-9]*$" | xargs -n1 kill
```